# Symfony 3: How to access controllers outside AppBundle/Controller?

Tags: php, controller, symfony

I'm trying to configure my routing.yml in a way that I can access controllers in a folder outside the AppBundle/Controller one.

I have a controller "AController" in AppBundle/it

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\it;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class AController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/a")
     * @param $name
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return $this->render('', array('name' => $name));
    }
}
```

and this is the routing.yml file:

```
app:
resource: "@AppBundle/it/"

type:     annotation
```

When I try to call this controller I get this exception:

```
Class \Account does not exist in `B:\xampp\htdocs\YourTeam\src\AppBundle/it/     (which is being imported from   "B:\xampp\htdocs\YourTeam\app/config\routing.yml").`
500 Internal Server Error - FileLoaderLoadException
1 linked Exception: ReflectionException »
```

Comment: What's the name of your file which houses this class (`AController`)?

Comment: AController.php

Comment: That error may be caused by another resource which needs, as dependency, that class (`Account`), and you didn't declared and implemented the class.